# How to set "end" parameters based on conditions inside print

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to print a list object with 5 items in a for loop, would like to print only the 3rd item(i.e. `_ == 2`) with new line while discarding newlines for other items.

I understand that I can achieve the desired result by converting the integer '2' as string and then concatenating it with a new line character, but is there a way to specify "new" parameters based on conditions in the print function?

Here is the desired result

```
012
34
```

```
for _ in range(5):
    print(str(_) + "\n" if _== 2 else _ , end='')
```

Obviously syntax error is preventing the use of new parameter in condition.

*syntax_err.py*

```
for _ in range(5):
    print((_ , end='') if _!= 2 else _)
```

nor can I do this:

```
for _ in range(5):
    print(_ if _== 2 else (_, end=''))
```

Comment: A generator expression needs to be parenthesised if it's not the only argument. Note the underscore typically represents a value that isn't going to be used, it's very confusing to see it here.

Comment: @jonrsharpe For reference: [What is the purpose of the single underscore “_” variable in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5893163/4518341)

Comment: @wjandrea yes, exactly.

Comment: BTW, welcome to SO! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips. This is a decent first question, keep it up! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for x in range(5):
    end = "\n" if x == 2 else ""
    print(x, end=end)
```

Comment: Thanks heaps! Didn't know you could use conditional statement for end parameter in print function.....

Answer (score 1):

You can give a conditional expression to the keyword argument, `end`.

```
for i in range(5):
    print(i, end="\n" if i==2 else '')
```

Output:

```
012
34
```

By the way, a single underscore [usually represents a throwaway variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5893163/4518341), which makes your code confusing, so I'm using `i` instead.